# Convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{e^{i n x}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I'm tring to show in an excersice the convergence of

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{e^{i n x}}{n}, \;-\pi<x<\pi.
$$

Indeed we could wirte

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{e^{i n x}}{n} = -\log(1-e^{ix}),
$$

but I think this is not effective in showing its convergence, since one can take $x=0$.

The hint of the excersice (in fact, the excersice 8 in Chapter 2 of Stein's *Fourerier Analysis*) suggests to use Dirichlet's test. In this way, it's easy to see that $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ goes to $0$ monotonically for some $\alpha > 0$, but I find it difficult to show the boundedness of a summation of $e^{i n x}$.

Comment: Use can use the geometric sum formula to show the boundedness of $\sum e^{i n x}$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @MartinR That's true, thank you very much. I even tried this at the beginging but missed the answer.